# How to fire update query in pattern [table_name.column_name] in php with ADODB?

Tags: php, adodb-php

I have to fire an update query through my php application with ADODB. ADODB doesn't update records if the field names are specified as `table_name.column_name`.

If I remove the table name prefix the query properly updates my values. Please suggest if there is any configuration. In my application I am allowed to have table name as prefix always.

```php
$conn = NewADOConnection($dsn);
$table = 'cus_tbl';
$record = [];
$record["cus_tbl.cus_firstname"] = 'Lyan';
$record["cus_tbl.cus_surname"] = 'King';
$where = "cus_tbl.cus_id=1";

$conn->autoExecute($table, $record, 'UPDATE', $where);
```

Answer (score 0):

any reason behind use of table name prefix ?

Comment: We have column names defined as constants in the application like table_name.column_name. Later we will use the same constants for framing queries.

Comment: Please add your question as the comment, not as an answer.